# My 2D ArrayList output gives cumulative value?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need some help. The actual case here is, the program I code will read several text document and each text document have different count of words. I want to keep these words into 2D ArrayList as it provides dynamic size based on the currently existing number of text documents and the words count in each of  the text document.

However, after several testing has been done, the output given is not as I expected. To make things simpler, I make this example code as a reference. How I use the 2D ArrayList is the same as I use for the actual Case.

```
    ArrayList<List<String>> twoDWords = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> oneDword = new ArrayList<String>();

    String word = "";
    String[] words = new String[5];

    System.out.println("Want like these(Using 2D ArrayList):");
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Array - "+i +": ");
        word += "myArray ";
        words[i] = word;
        System.out.println(word);
    }

    System.out.println("\nBut Get these output:");
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        oneDword.add(words[i]);
        twoDWords.add(oneDword);
        //oneDword.clear();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< twoDWords.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Array - "+i +": ");
        for(int j = 0; j< twoDWords.get(i).size(); j++)
        {
            System.out.print(twoDWords.get(i).get(j)+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

This is the output:
[image]

The output looks like it gives out the latest cumulative value only repetitively. As you can see in the code, I also try to use clear() method to reset the array but it then gives empty value.

I hope somebody can help me in this problem. Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Christopher solution, you shall use foreach loop since it is easier to read:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    oneDword.add(words[i]);
    twoDWords.add(oneDword);
    oneDword = new ArrayList<String>(); // --> You need this since 'oneDword' contains the previous values as well and it'll keep adding new values to this list.
    //oneDword.clear();
}

for(List<String> al: twoDWords) {
  for(String s: al) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the very same array object which is stored in every element of your array twoDwords. You need to create a new array for each element of your array twoDWords by using "new" inside the loop:

```
   ..........
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
        {   oneDword = new ArrayList<String>(); //<-------
            oneDword.add(words[i]);
            twoDWords.add(oneDword);
            //oneDword.clear();
        }
    .........
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand what you are doing wrong you need to think about method argument references. 
Specially this line:

```
twoDWords.add(oneDword);
```

In this line you are adding a "reference" of oneDword to your twoDWords list. You are adding references to the same oneDword every time. Therefore, you end up with a list size of 5 but they all hold references to your oneDword list (which you keep growing in your middle loop.